# How to host node code in virtual directory

Tags: node.js, virtualhost, virtual-directory

I have 2 separate code of node application. I have already deployed node code on a windows server. Code runs on port 80 so when I hit my domain like `www.myproject.com` it loads my home page of my node server.

When I hit `www.myproject.com/admin` it should give me the admin page form my other node js code.

Comment: i have done above thing using load balancers :D.

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit short on information in your question, but I'll do my best with what you've given. Assuming you have 2 instances of node on your machine, but want a user to only access one, and you are using express, I would suggest an http proxy on one to route to the other such as:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy

Setup your /admin route to access your uri of your 2nd instance. Hope that helps.